# pdftotext return blank but pdf has multiple lines and multiple pages why?

Tags: python, ocr, apache-tika, pdftotext

```
import pdftotext

# Load your PDF
with open("docs/doc1.pdf", "rb") as f:
    docs = pdftotext.PDF(f)

print(docs[0])
```

this code print blank for this specific file, if i change the file it is giving me result.
I tried even apache Tika. Tika also return None, How to solve this problem?

One thing I would like to mention here is that **pdf is made of multiple images**

Here is the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FDTHxf59ZEYlhbiRuxpNFjrhcyYaA3_C/view?usp=sharing)
This is sample pdf, not the original one. but i want to extract text from the pdf something like this

Comment: Can you share the file in question?

Comment: @tevemadar I can't file has some sensitive information. sorry

Comment: That's understandable, just in that case it becomes hard to reproduce the issue. If you know how that particular pdf was created, perhaps you can try making one with "neutral" content, and share it (of course, after checking it still produces the same issue).

Comment: @tevemadar ok I'll try to create a pdf similar to that and then upload it in my question

Comment: Is it a scan of a PDF? So actually a PDF of images of the text?

Comment: @tevemadar I added the sample pdf in the question. please look at at the file